# ¿Cómo imprimir correctamente un vector de tipo String que almacena imagenes ASCII?

Tags: java, netbeans, consola

' package principal;

```
 import java.util.Scanner;


 public class Juego {

 ImagenP images;
 String[] imgPokemons;


String tecla;

public Juego() {
    images = new ImagenP();

    imgPokemons = new String[5];

}

//Creando el método Agregar pokemon.
public void seleccionar() {

    Pokemon pokemon[] = new Pokemon[5];

    pokemon[0] = new Pokemon(" Bulbasaur", "vivo", 10);
    pokemon[1] = new Pokemon(" Charizard", "vivo", 10);
    pokemon[2] = new Pokemon(" Squirtle", "vivo", 10);
    pokemon[3] = new Pokemon(" Charmander", "vivo", 10);
    pokemon[4] = new Pokemon(" Spearow", "vivo", 10);

    imgPokemons[0] = images.pok1;
    imgPokemons[1] = images.pok2;
    imgPokemons[2] = images.pok3;
    imgPokemons[3] = images.pok4;
    imgPokemons[4] = images.pok5;

    for (Pokemon pokemon1 : pokemon) {
        int pok = 0;
        System.out.println((pok + 1) + pokemon1.mensaje());


    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < imgPokemons.length; i++) {
        System.out.println( imgPokemons[i]);

    }}
}


 }'
```

Las imagenes están en una clase aparte.

' package principal;

```
public class ImagenP {

String pok1;
String pok2;
String pok3;
String pok4;
String pok5;

public ImagenP() {
  '
```

Son muy grandes las imágenes que mejor he decidido colocar la foto para que puedan ver las formas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un pequeño menú para andar el juego.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    int  opcion ;





    do {


        System.out.println("\n****TAMAGOTCHI****");

        System.out.println("1. Seleccionar Pokemon");
        System.out.println("2. Alimentar");
        System.out.println("3. Ejercitar");
        System.out.println("4. Estado");
        System.out.println("5. Matar");
        System.out.println("6. Revivir");
        System.out.println("7. Salir\n");

        System.out.println("Seleccione opción:");
         opcion = entrada.nextInt();

        switch (opcion) {
            case 1:

                seleccion();

                break; 

          default:

        }

    //} while (letra.equals("S") || letra.equals("n"));
    }while (opcion != 7);

}

private static void seleccion() {
    Juego J = new Juego();
    J.seleccionar();
} '
```

Mi problema es que anda imprimiendo varias veces una imagen en lugar de imprimir el resto de imagenes que son 5.

Comment: Creo que sería mejor mover el texto de la "imagen" a un archivo de texto y cargar el contenido de dicho archivo cuando necesites mostrar la imagen.

Comment: +1 a lo que te dice @Luiggi Mendoza. No veo necesidad de almacenar tanto caracter. Además, la concatenación exagerada trae problemas de rendimiento.

Answer (score 1):

El error debe estar en constructor de la clase `ImagenP` porque hice una prueba con el código que colocaste y no hubo problemas. Revisa que no estes asignando los Strings con las imágenes al mismo atributo `pok1, pok2, ...`

Por otro lado, puedes mejorar éste código:

```
int pok = 0;
for (Pokemon pokemon1 : pokemon) {
    System.out.println((++pok) + pokemon1.mensaje());
    for (int i = 0; i < imgPokemons.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(imgPokemons[i]);
    }
}
```

Y en el main igual puedes hacer:

```
switch (opcion) {
    case 1:
        new Juego().seleccionar();
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Opción no válida");
        break;
    }
```

Y eliminas el método del final:

```
private static void seleccion() {
    Juego J = new Juego();
    J.seleccionar();
}
```